# Cannot call React.Component.setState() with webpack-dev-server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack-dev-server, setstate

I have a fairly vanilla `react` component in which I would like to track the value of an `input`. The component is defined as follows.

```
import React from 'react';

class MyInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: 'initial value' };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (<input onChange={this.handleChange} />);
  }
}
```

This works perfectly if I compile the code using `webpack` but when I try to use `webpack-dev-server` with hot reloading I get this error:

```
(unknown) Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component.
```

I've checked the mounting and the component is definitely mounted when this warning is spit out but the state doesn't update. Everything that comes up when you google the warning has to do with people calling it after the component has unmounted which, again, is not what is happening here. Any ideas what could be going on in this case?

Comment: In the return statement, there's a typo - `nChange` should be `onChange` - might not have anything to do with your problem, but worth fixing.

Comment: Thanks, this was just a typo in copying it over and formatting here.

Comment: restarting the server might be worth a shot because hot reloading stops working sometime

Comment: I have bumped into the same thing.  When I disable the hot replacement, everything works.  I have meticulously threaded through `react-hot-boilerplate#next` and compared (I'm using `react-hot-loader@3.0.0-beta.7` ) and have not spotted any errors.  So this is a problem somewhere, just not sure where.

Comment: @Ivanna I'm having the same issue. Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I used your component (fixed the onChange typo) and added an export statment. Works fine!

```
import React from 'react';

class MyInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: 'initial value' };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
}

render() {
    return (
        <input onChange={this.handleChange} />
    );
  }
}
export default MyInput;
```

Comment: Did you try it with `webpack-dev-server`? I say in the original question that the component works fine, it's some issue with the hot-reloading.